# Do we need an IC to make a USB hub?

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, hub

I am planning to make a USB hub for my PC.

I was thinking about just making it like this:

[image: USB Hub]

When I search the internet for circuit diagrams, there are many circuit diagrams with an IC.  Must an IC be used in a USB hub or can I just continue with the image above?

Comment: USB is not a multi-drop shared bus. You absolutely need a hub, for a multitude of reasons ranging from the physical layer to the protocol. If you could do as you propose, we would have splitter cables rather than hubs.

Comment: @nanofarad. Thank you, I'm still confused. Are you saying that I should use an IC for usb hub. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You need an IC to provide the technical functionality of a USB hub.

Comment: @nanofarad. Thank you for giving clarification to my doubt.

Comment: You can buy usb hub ICs [examples here](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Interface-ICs/USB-Interface-IC/_/N-45lw3?P=1yx0p2iZ1yzudq8) BUT they are hard to solder and not fully trivial to use. Buying a hub is generally better. An older USB2 HUB  is adequate for many tasks - and building a high speed one takes special care. || Where are you located.

Comment: @Russell McMahon. Thank you for your advice and I'm from India and I live in a rural place where no one sells it. So, maybe I will go out to city and buy them. I don't want to buy from Amazon because it costs more than buying from an local shop.

Comment: You have to consider the value of your time. With Amazon you are essentially paying to have it delivered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you propose is not an USB hub.

An USB hub is an active device and implementing it requires an IC.